# GTK Dialog Margin not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

I have created a little dialog with a grid. Here is it:

[image]

But I don't understand why the margin not working:

```
class PreferencesDialog(Gtk.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "Preferences", parent, 0)

        self.set_default_size(300, 300)

        grid = Gtk.Grid(column_spacing=10,
                         row_spacing=10)

        label = Gtk.Label("Custom Location")
        switch = Gtk.Switch()
        switch.set_active(False)

        grid.add(label)
        grid.margin_left = 20
        grid.margin_right = 20
        grid.margin_top = 20
        grid.margin_bottom = 20

        grid.attach(switch, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        box = self.get_content_area()
        box.add(grid)
        self.show_all()
```

And I see that the size of the window : 300x300 is not working anymore.
Could you help me?

Comment: What's wrong with the window's size? It works just fine on my PC.

Comment: Yeah I see it now. Thanls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gtk widgets are based on [GObject](http://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which means you have to access the widget's properties through the [`props` attribute](http://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/api/properties.html):

```
grid.props.margin_left = 20
grid.props.margin_right = 20
grid.props.margin_top = 20
grid.props.margin_bottom = 20
```

Alternatively, you can use the [setter functions](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.set_margin_bottom):

```
grid.set_margin_left(20)
grid.set_margin_right(20)
grid.set_margin_top(20)
grid.set_margin_bottom(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer is the way to go but I wanted to add that as of Gtk version 3.12 `set_margin_left()`, and `set_margin_right()` were deprecated.

The right way now is to use `set_margin_start()`, and `set_margin_end()`.

Here is the [documentation](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.set_margin_right) and a modified example from the selected answer.

```
grid.set_margin_start(20)
grid.set_margin_end(20)
```

The setter functions for the top and bottom are the same.

P.S - I am new to Gtk API. I came across this answer and got the deprecation warning when I tried it.